# Sort array by object properties but with nil? condition in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting, haml

I have an array of users which may or may not have an array of startups. The startup object has a property name.

I want to sort the array of users by the name of the startup. But I obviously get an error when the user object does have a startup.

I tried the following code after going through some of the solutions on StackOverflow. I'm using HAML thats why no "end" keyword

```
- @users.sort do |a, b|
  - a.startup.nil? ? -1 : b.startup.nil? ? 1 : a.startup[0].name <=> b. startup[0].name
```

but I got the following error.

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

On trying

```
- @users.sort do |a, b|
  - a.startup[0].nil? ? -1 : b.startup[0].nil? ? 1 : a.startup[0].name <=> b. startup[0].name
```

The users array was not sorted at all.

Note: I referred to this SO post [Sorting an array of arrays in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194662/sorting-an-array-of-arrays-in-ruby)

I also tried

```
  -@users.sort{|a,b| a.startup[0].name && b.startup[0].name ? a.startup[0].name <=> b.startup[0].name : a.startup[0].name ? -1 : 1 }
```

which is essentially

```
foo.sort{|a,b| a && b ? a <=> b : a ? -1 : 1 }
```

from the SO entry: [sorting a ruby array of objects by an attribute that could be nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808318/sorting-a-ruby-array-of-objects-by-an-attribute-that-could-be-nil)

even this gave the error

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

EDIT: When the user does not have a startup, I want that user to be placed at the end of the array.

Comment: If a user doesn't have a startup, then how do you want to sort those?

Comment: To put you on the right track, you might review what evaluates to nil in Ruby. (Or to be less subtle, what happens when `User#startup` returns an empty array?)

Comment: @Tacoman667 When the user does not have a startup, I want that user to be placed at the end of the array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you probably want to do this sorting in your controller, or even in your model. Putting it in your view makes it a bit noisy.

Second, this solution should work for you. It's fairly short.

```
@users.sort_by { |u| u.startup.nil? || u.startup.blank? ? 255.chr : u.startup[0].name }
```

Using `255.chr` will push all empty (`[]`) and null (`nil`) arrays to the back of the array, as you specified in your comment that you'd like to do that. I assume that there's a cleaner way of representing `255.chr`, but I haven't been able to find one.

If a user with no startups is represented as an empty array (`[]`), then you can remove `u.startup.nil? ||` from that line of code. Similarly, if a user with no startups is represented as `nil`, then you can remove `|| u.startup.blank?` from it. The code as is assumes that a user with no startups can either have an empty or null array.

Comment: Brilliant!!! Thanks a million. It worked flawlessly. I dont have the upvote privilege yet. Will upvote once I have enough points.

Comment: No problem! It puts me one step closer to the Unsung Hero badge!

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the problem, you can use [#sort_by](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by) instead of sort, which only requires you to tell what value should be used to compare things.

```
@users.sort_by {|u| u.startup.try(:first).try(:name) ? 0 : 1 }
```

We can also use [#try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) to return `nil` if the method does not respond to the method we asked.

If you still get errors you should use the `try` method where you print the startup name